# Kivy: Change image during animation

Tags: python, kivy

With my code I want to demonstrate moving body on trajectory. Body is symbolized by image. I need to change image during animation. Variant of image is influenced by parametr *orient* in method trace_animation. Moving body is variable *self.dot* I tried to separate sequential animaton to particular animamations (each part own image), but I didn't obtain applicable results. What must I add to code?

```
class Scene(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def draw_scene(self):

        for i in range(0,self.count_tile):
            pos, source = self.gase.par_img(i)
            img = Image(source=source, pos=pos)
            self.add_widget(img)
            self.liTile.append(img)

        self.dot = Image(source= self.gase.tile_name[2], pos=(170,0)) # moving body
        self.add_widget(self.dot)

        return

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.gase.change_tile(touch.x, touch.y)
        self.draw_scene()
        pass

    def trace_animation(self, li_trace):
        self.animation = Animation(pos = li_trace[0], duration = 0.25)
        del li_trace[0]
        orient = 1      # parameter which influences variant of image
        for pos in li_trace:

            self.animation += Animation(pos = pos, duration = 0.25)
            orient *=-1
        self.animation.start(self.dot)
```

Comment: I have never done this, but I would try using the canvas and pushmatrix/popmatrix as in https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__canvas__rotation__py.html

Then adjust the `angle` via the `on_progress` event during the animation.